# What is the legal status of Homebrewing where you live?

Tags: legal

So, I am quite the nerd, and one of the things I nerd about is the law in general, and in particular the legal standing of specific things around the world, such as photography, copyright and homebrewing.

The question is pretty clear, but I would love some historical background, too, if you have it.

Comment: This should either be closed as there's not a "best" answer, or (better yet) converted to a Wiki.

Comment: I don't think any answers to this will be useful outside of particular places at a particular time.   There are better forums for gathering this sort of information, and one of the answers below addresses that.

Answer (score 2):

Before asking about maybe it would be good to consult the oracle (i.e. google):

http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/pages/government-affairs/statutes

Answer (score 0):

Here in NJ, we needed a $20/year permit to homebrew.  Just this year, the governor signed a law removing that permit, so we can brew up to the federal limit (100 gals/year for an individual, 200/year for a household) legally without any permits.